# Can not downgrade bundler for heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to push my project to heroku and I am getting this error.

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.0
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
```

I am also using rvm.

It seems like the heroku bundler uses 1.11.2 so I am trying to downgrade my version from 1.12.5.

I did gem uninstall bundler then gem install bundler --version '1.11.2'

However when I do bundler -v, it's still showing 1.12.5

But when I do gem uninstall bundler, it shows
Successfully uninstalled bundler-1.11.2

I still can't push and I am getting that error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps;

http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/UPGRADING_rdoc.html

And one more thing I think your bundler is installed in the rvm default gemset i.e. system gemset.

Try checking this;

Do `rvm list` in terminal, this will give you output like this;

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.4 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.4 [ x86_64 ]
```

Now do rvm gemset list; this will give you out put as this;

```
(default)
   global
   some-gemset
```

Check which gemset its used in your system, it can be identified as `=> global` whenever you do the `rvm gemset list`.

Now when you identified in which gemset you currently in, do something like this `rvm use 1.9.2@global`

Then;

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

Or in a single step you can do it like this;

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler
```

And then install your desired bundler version like this;

```
gem install bundler --version '1.11.2'
```

Hope this might help you.